# python to identify curved segments

Tags: python, gis

I posted a similar question on the ESRI forums, but the posting seems to have gone cold :(

Anyone know how to identify if an ESRI feature class contains curved, (arcs) segment(s)?

I have several thousand feat. classes, something via python would be great!

thanks!

**Edit: update**

someone at esri has commented that you can detect if a polyline feature contains an arc segment by comparing the "truecentroid" and "centroid" of the feature. if truecent. <> cent: then the feature contains an arc. This is OK, but I'm still lacking a  solution for polygons, as the above method does not work.

Here's what we have so far:

```
lstFCs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "Polyline")

for fc in lstFCs:
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
    print fc
    for row in rows:
        type = row.Shape
        geom = str(type.centroid.X)
        truegeom = str(type.trueCentroid.X)
        if geom != truegeom:
            print row.ObjectID

del row, rows
```

Comment: This question needs more background information to be answerable.

Comment: i have about 160 geodatabases, each containing several feat. datasets and feat. classes. The feat. classes are of polygon, polyline and point geometry. I can access each of the feat. classes, and exclude the point classes easily using                 gp.describe(). I can also access the individual segments that collectively make up a polygon or polyline using gp.searchcursor on the gp.getpart(array). What I don't know is how to detect, whether the individual segments are straight line segments or arcs, (also called curved segments).

Comment: This does not work for any poor souls who may have found themselves here.

Answer (score 0):

For the polygons I think you have to first loop through the rings of the polygons to find polylines and then you can examine the polylines as you do in your code.

Sorry I cannot help you any further since I don't have ArcGIS installed (and it is all long time ago I worked with ArcGIS). You might get better response on [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import arcpy, json

arcpy.env.workspace = r"..." #Your database
lstFCs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "Polyline")

for fc in lstFCs:
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
    print fc
    for row in rows:
        jsonGeometry = json.loads(row.Shape.JSON)
        if 'curve' in jsonGeometry or 'curveRings' in jsonGeometry:
            print row.ObjectID
    del row, rows
```

Comment: description to your answer would make it better

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard function in Geospatial SQL that is useful for what you want to do. It is called ST_CurvosityIndex(LineString). Applied to a feature LineString gives it an index number between 1-0. 1 means a straight line, 0 a string of lines that have start and end points at the same coordinate.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any other information on how the algorithm behind this SQL/MM statement was implemented, but I think you can email Alessandro Furieri a.furieri@lqt.it, who developed that SQL statement, asking him about the algorithm that distinguishes how curved the LineString feature is.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).